# Strechted out picture in ImageView

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I want to show the image from a location from my phone in ImageView. But when I use scaletype FIT_XY the image gets stretched out.

Here is the code for my layout

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:layout_above="@+id/cancel_show_war">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/show_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/show_startdate"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/show_enddate"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"/>
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/show_image_war"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/cancel_show_war"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/mybutton"
            android:text="@string/cancel_input"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The code where I get the image and put it in my ImageView

```
File img_file = new File(imgPath);
        ImageView imgView = findViewById(R.id.show_image_war);
        imgView.setImageURI(Uri.fromFile(img_file));
        imgView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
```

And finally a picture of the strechted out picture

[image]

Comment: FitXY stretches the image to fit the view bounds so that is the intended outcome

Comment: I would think that it uses the scrollview and puts the full picture as outcome

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?